# Termux was unable to install the bootstrap packages

Tags: termux

After doing some research, it mention that the bootstrap in this url (http://termux.net/bootstrap/) must be download and install before one can use Termux.

So, how do I install the bootstrap? or do I put the bootstrap files into a particular folder in the phone before install Termux? or something else I need to do? or are there alternative methods to get Termux installed and running without connecting to the Internet?

(Note: The phone is not connect to the Internet. The phone need to have Termux installed with all prerequisite packages, such as bootstrap.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install that bootstrap package without internet, you need root access.

The easiest way I've found is with Titanium Backup. You can install Termux on another device, bootstrap it then back it up with TB, and transfer the TB backup to the offline device and restore. It's also convenient for batch deploy.

**If you want to manually install the bootstrap package** via a shell (another Terminal Emulator or ADB shell), here's a possible method (I haven't tested it myself, but I think it's mostly correct). As said before, manual installation also requires root access.

First download the ZIP of the correct architecture and create these directories:

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/home
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
```

And extract the ZIP completely to `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`.

Then create some symbolic links because they're required for Termux to work. The instruction to creating those symbolic links are stored in `SYMLINKS.txt` and you need to process that.

Well, putting Unicode characters in such a text file isn't a good practice because it makes it hard to parse. Maybe you can try this tool ([Meta Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315753/350567), [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ibug/pen/qMvKdM)) on a desktop browser. First click "Run Code Snippet" to enable it. Paste the content of `SYMLINKS.txt` to the text box, click `Convert` and run the output as shell commands. Make sure you're running those `ln` commands in `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`.

Finally, correct the permissions, ownerships and SELinux contexts. Run the following commands. You can use the "vanilla" toolset in `/system/bin` for this job. They perform well here.

```
ROOT=/data/data/com.termux/files
UID=$(stat -c %u $ROOT)
chown -R $UID.$UID $ROOT
chmod -R 0755 $ROOT/usr/bin $ROOT/usr/libexec
```

If you're running Android 7 (API 24) or up, run this command in addition:

```
chcon -R u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 $ROOT
```

Answer (score 1):

Termux was unable to install the bootstrap packages

I had the same error and I was connected to internet. I had to go into settings and put Termux on internal shared storage and finally got it to install